# MaxMind/GeoIP Error calling Location class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, geoip, maxmind

I am successfully using the MaxMind GeoIP Legacy .NET API (https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-csharp2) Country Class to retrieve Country code based on IP. I am, however, running into issues trying to use the Location class. Below is my code:

```
try
{
    // capture visitors IP
    string visitorIp = Model.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_Forwarded_For"];
    visitorIp = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(visitorIp) ? Request.UserHostAddress : visitorIp;


    string geoIpPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/GeoIP.dat");
    LookupService ls = new LookupService(geoIpPath, LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
    //get country of the ip address
    Country c = ls.getCountry(visitorIp);
    string countryCode = c.getCode() != "--" ? c.getCode() : "US";


    // Capture country code as cookie
    if (Request.Cookies["GeoIP"] == null)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("GeoIP", countryCode);
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }

    string geoIpCityPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/GeoLiteCity.dat");
    LookupService lsCity = new LookupService(geoIpCityPath, LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
    Location l = ls.getLocation(visitorIp);
    <h1>Postal Code = @l.postalCode.ToString()</h1>


}
catch (Exception e)
{
    <p>@e</p>
}
```

The string countryCode is tracked without error. When I try to use the Location class I get the following error message:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required.
>   Parameter name: length at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32
>   sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32
>   length, Boolean reliable) at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray,
>   Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex,
>   Int32 length) at LookupService.getLocation(Int64 ipnum) in
>   ~\Models\LookupService.cs:line
>   582 at LookupService.getLocation(IPAddress addr) in
>   ~\Models\LookupService.cs:line
>   443 at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__GeoIP_cshtml.Execute() in
>   ~\Views\Shared_GeoIP.cshtml:line 34

Thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the legacy API rather than the [GeoIP2 API](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-dotnet)? The former is a bit of a mess generally.

Comment: @oschwald The project I am integrating with is still on .Net 4.0 so the newer version may not be an option for now (wish that was not the case).

Comment: If you did want to use the GeoIP2 API, you could use 2.4.0, which is the last version to support .NET 4.0.

Comment: As for your above issue, are you using the version off of NuGet? That was done by a third party and, I believe, it is out of date and may be missing some countries, which could cause the above issue. Are you getting it on all IPs?

Comment: @oschwald How would I obtain v2.4.0 of GeoIP2 API?  As for the Legacy API I believe it was obtained directly from Github not nuget. I will run some more tests for various IPs, but so far seems to error on  all that I've tried. Thanks for all your input btw!

Comment: @oschwald I found v2.4.0 release of GeoIP2 API, but unable to compile the source.  Would you be able to provide me the compiled files required?

Comment: @oschwald In regards to the legacy API I compiled the src from (https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-csharp2/tree/master/src) and using the Geo Lite DB files from (http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/). I tested a handful of IPs and get same error each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest filing a bug against the GeoIP Legacy API. It sounds like there is an issue reading the database. You could also try the version off of NuGet, which is a fork of the version on GitHub.

As for GeoIP2, you can get a pre-compiled 2.4.0 package using NuGet:

```
Install-Package MaxMind.GeoIP2 -Version 2.4.0
```

Comment: I installed the GeoIP 2.4.0 NuGet package and it worked perfectly, thanks!  I will file a bug against the GeoIP Legacy API. Thanks again for all your assistance and help!